# Lost Connection to MySQL Server During Query Error 2013

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

Every time I try to execute the query I get the following error:

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

What I did is I changed the read time out to 600, but I still get the same problem.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Did you restart the MySQL server process after making that change? Did this "lost connection" happen at a particular time? Get your stopwatch ready.

Comment: I did restart, and it happens after the '600' runs out

Comment: If your query takes a very long time you may need to crank that even higher.

Comment: @tadman how would I know the time it requires?

Comment: You don't know until it finishes and that can depend on a large number of factors, many beyond your control. I just had a 70 hour query fail.

Comment: @tadman holy cow! well thanks ill try increasing the numbers and see what happens