# Mysql Installed in EC2 T3.Large: Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, database, timeout, connection-timeout

I got the

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query error.

I have 80 million records in a table.

When I execute few basic queries i don't get any errors. When I execute aggregate query I am getting a connection to MySQL server during query error after 2 hours.

In my case even if the query takes more than 10 hours also that's fine, but I need that particular query to be executed.

I know this is a duplicate question. I have made most of the suggested changes reading stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975796/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query-error-2013), even though the query is not executing.

The current settings I have modified is:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=67108864;
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=6026531840;
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=36000;
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=36000;
```

I executing the query using MYSQL Workbench and also tried with python script.

Comment: even with the strongest hardware if a table is lockt you can waut forever, so check if the a locks prsent

Comment: Please don't use Indian words here. People aren't going to understand what are "crore records". Also, you should include your table descriptions, indexes and the query you're using. Without them people are just guessing.